# TensorFlow using LSTMs for generating text

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I would like to use tensorflow to generate text and have been modifying the LSTM tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks) code to do this, however my initial solution seems to generate nonsense, even after training for a long time, it does not improve. I fail to see why. The idea is to start with a zero matrix and then generate one word at a time.

This is the code, to which I've added the two functions below
https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

The generator looks as follows

```
def generate_text(session,m,eval_op):

    state = m.initial_state.eval()

    x = np.zeros((m.batch_size,m.num_steps), dtype=np.int32)

    output = str()
    for i in xrange(m.batch_size):
        for step in xrange(m.num_steps):
            try:
                # Run the batch 
                # targets have to bee set but m is the validation model, thus it should not train the neural network
                cost, state, _, probabilities = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op, m.probabilities],
                                                            {m.input_data: x, m.targets: x, m.initial_state: state})

                # Sample a word-id and add it to the matrix and output
                word_id = sample(probabilities[0,:])
                output = output + " " + reader.word_from_id(word_id)
                x[i][step] = word_id

            except ValueError as e:
                print("ValueError")

    print(output)
```

I have added the variable "probabilities" to the ptb_model and it is simply a softmax over the logits.

```
self._probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

And the sampling:

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
    # helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    a = np.log(a) / temperature
    a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
    return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1))
```

Answer (score 18):

I have been working toward the exact same goal, and just got it to work. You have many of the right modifications here, but I think you've missed a few steps.

First, for generating text you need to create a different version of the model which represents only a single timestep. The reason is that we need to sample each output y before we can feed it into the next step of the model. I did this by making a new config which sets `num_steps` and `batch_size` both equal to 1.

```
class SmallGenConfig(object):
  """Small config. for generation"""
  init_scale = 0.1
  learning_rate = 1.0
  max_grad_norm = 5
  num_layers = 2
  num_steps = 1 # this is the main difference
  hidden_size = 200
  max_epoch = 4
  max_max_epoch = 13
  keep_prob = 1.0
  lr_decay = 0.5
  batch_size = 1
  vocab_size = 10000
```

I also added a probabilities to the model with these lines:

```
self._output_probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

and

```
@property
def output_probs(self):
  return self._output_probs
```

Then, there are a few differences in my `generate_text()` function. The first one is that I load saved model parameters from disk using the `tf.train.Saver()` object. Note that we do this after instantiating the PTBModel with the new config from above.

```
def generate_text(train_path, model_path, num_sentences):
  gen_config = SmallGenConfig()

  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-gen_config.init_scale,
                                                gen_config.init_scale)    
    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
      m = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=gen_config)

    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver = tf.train.Saver() 
    saver.restore(session, model_path)
    print("Model restored from file " + model_path)
```

The second difference is that I get the lookup table from ids to word strings (I had to write this function, see the code below).

```
    words = reader.get_vocab(train_path)
```

I set up the initial state the same way you do, but then I set up the initial token in a different manner. I want to use the "end of sentence" token so that I'll start my sentence with the right types of words. I looked through the word index and found that `<eos>` happens to have index 2 (deterministic) so I just hard-coded that in. Finally, I wrap it in a 1x1 Numpy Matrix so that it is the right type for the model inputs.

```
    state = m.initial_state.eval()
    x = 2 # the id for '<eos>' from the training set
    input = np.matrix([[x]])  # a 2D numpy matrix
```

Finally, here's the part where we generate sentences. Note that we tell `session.run()` to compute the `output_probs` and the `final_state`. And we give it the input and the state. In the first iteration the input is `<eos>` and the state is the `initial_state`, but on subsequent iterations we give as input our last sampled output, and we pass the state along from the last iteration. Note also that we use the `words` list to look up the word string from the output index.

```
    text = ""
    count = 0
    while count < num_sentences:
      output_probs, state = session.run([m.output_probs, m.final_state],
                                   {m.input_data: input,
                                    m.initial_state: state})
      x = sample(output_probs[0], 0.9)
      if words[x]=="<eos>":
        text += ".\n\n"
        count += 1
      else:
        text += " " + words[x]
      # now feed this new word as input into the next iteration
      input = np.matrix([[x]])
```

Then all we have to do is print out the text we accumulated.

```
    print(text)
  return
```

That's it for the `generate_text()` function.

Finally, let me show you the function definition for `get_vocab()`, which I put in reader.py.

```
def get_vocab(filename):
  data = _read_words(filename)

  counter = collections.Counter(data)
  count_pairs = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

  words, _ = list(zip(*count_pairs))

  return words
```

The last thing you need to do is to be able to save the model after training it, which looks like

```
save_path = saver.save(session, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

And that's the model that you'll load from disk later when generating text.

There was one more problem: I found that sometimes the probability distribution produced by the Tensorflow softmax function didn't sum exactly to 1.0. When the sum was larger than 1.0, `np.random.multinomial()` throws an error. So I had to write my own sampling function, which looks like this

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
  a = np.log(a) / temperature
  a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
  r = random.random() # range: [0,1)
  total = 0.0
  for i in range(len(a)):
    total += a[i]
    if total>r:
      return i
  return len(a)-1
```

When you put all this together, the small model was able to generate me some cool sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I use your code, it seems not right. So I modify it a little, it seems work.
Here is my code, and I'm not sure it is right:

```
def generate_text(session,m,eval_op, word_list):
output = []
for i in xrange(20):
    state = m.initial_state.eval()
    x = np.zeros((1,1), dtype=np.int32)
    y = np.zeros((1,1), dtype=np.int32)
    output_str = ""
    for step in xrange(100):
        if True:
            # Run the batch 
            # targets have to bee set but m is the validation model, thus it should not train the neural network
            cost, state, _, probabilities = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op, m.probabilities],
                                                        {m.input_data: x, m.targets: y, m.initial_state: state})
            # Sample a word-id and add it to the matrix and output
            word_id = sample(probabilities[0,:])
            if (word_id<0) or (word_id > len(word_list)):
                continue
            #print(word_id)
            output_str = output_str + " " + word_list[word_id]
            x[0][0] = word_id
    print(output_str)
    output.append(output_str)
return output
```